# ¿Cómo extraer datos de Excel usando Python?

Tags: python, excel

Hola buenas tardes me encuentro con el siguiente inconveniente, no sé cómo puedo extraer los datos marcados con el color amarillo y crear una lista con estos, son coordenadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código esta de la siguiente manera, pero el problema es que quiero automatizar esto por que necesito leer un archivo con demasiados datos, podría ser una función que salte cierto numero de celdas y lea los datos:

```py
import xlwings as xw
wb=xw.Book(r'C:\Users\Copicompu\Desktop\Libro2.xlsx')
c=wb.sheets[0]
C1=(c.range('B2').value,c.range('C2').value)
C2=(c.range('B2').value,c.range('C2').value)
C3=(c.range('B2').value,c.range('C2').value)
C4=(c.range('B2').value,c.range('C2').value)
C5=(c.range('B2').value,c.range('C2').value)
COORD=[C1,C2,C3,C4,C5]
```

El resultado a obtener sería de esta manera:

```py
[(691901.472, 9533766.6), (699718.671, 9553624.72), (693093.573,9587306.91), (674134.146, 9532237.66), (650824.07,9551999.63)]
```

Comment: pandas te hace la vida más fácil

Comment: como podria usar pandas en este caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca me cansaré de recomendar `pandas` a todos, es bastante sencillo y resuelve los problemas de forma muy fácil. Primero lo instalamos:

```
pip install pandas
```

Luego necesitaremos importarlo en nuestro proyecto y con ayuda de *aliasing* le pondremos un *alias*.

```py
import pandas as pd
```

El módulo `pandas` trae varias funciones para leer archivos, desde archivos de texto hasta `.xlsx`, aquí dependerá de lo que tu tengas, si es un `.csv` usarás `.read_csv`, si es un excel usarás `.read_excel`. Por defecto `pandas` identificará los nombres de las columnas y no tendrás que preocuparte de ello, también intuye el tipo de dato de las celdas que tengas (pero a veces se equivoca, no lo culpes). Al leer un archivo `pandas` retorna un nuevo tipo de dato llamado `DataFrame` que permite hacer miles de operaciones, pero para tu caso solo usaremos 2.

```py
df = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\Copicompu\Desktop\Libro2.xlsx") #en tu caso es un excel

#primera forma
data_1 = df.iloc[::3]

#segunda forma
data_2 = df.groupby("Estacion").agg({"UTMX":lambda x: list(x)[0], "UTMY":lambda x: list(x)[0]})

print(data_1, "\n")
print(data_2)
```

Dado que no mencionas la si el número de datos consecutivos es variable lo hice de 2 formas. La primera forma es para el caso en que el número de datos consecutivos sean iguales (3 consecutivos). En esta ocasión usamos *slicing* que sirve para obtener partes de una lista (aunque pandas redefine el método), la sintaxis es `[inicio:fin:paso]` (si no se especifica el inicio se usa 0 por defecto, para el fin se usa `len(list)` y para el paso `1`) dado que queremos siempre el primer elemento de cada 3 entonces hacemos `[::3]` lo que nos tomará los elementos de 3 en 3.

Para la segunda forma se contempla un escenario donde los datos consecutivos no sean siempre los mismos, y pensando que siempre se quiere el primer valor de cada `Estación` (y que no haya Estaciones repetidas después de las consecutivas). Lo que hacemos en este caso es usar `groupby` para agrupar según la estación, luego de agrupar usamos el método `agg` para realizar una operación sobre las columnas que especifiquemos en este caso `UTMX` y `UTMY` donde convertimos los datos agrupados en listas y obtenemos el primer elemento.

La forma que elijas dependerá de la estructura de tus datos, también te dejo la [documentación de pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) para que aprendas más sobre este módulo ampliamente utilizado por muchos expertos. Si tienes dudas puedes hacérmelas en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Aprecio mucho tu ayuda, es muy util para mi, revisare mas la documentacion de pandas para aprender mucho mas.

Comment: Un placer haberte ayudado, pandas es bastante útil y por eso también lo utilizan en IA. Si deseas saber más puedes leer algunas de mis respuestas o las de otros usuarios aquí en el sitio. Stack Overflow es un sitio donde encontrarás muchas cosas interesantes y por cierto, bienvenida a Stack Overflow :D.

Comment: Una duda mas, como podria organizar los datos de coordenadas en una lista de tuplas, como indique que deberia ser la salida                                                 [(691901.472, 9533766.6), (699718.671, 9553624.72), (693093.573,9587306.91), (674134.146, 9532237.66), (650824.07,9551999.63)]

Comment: para el primer caso (variable `data_1`) harías esto `data_1.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: tuple(x), axis=1)` y para el segundo caso deberás hacer primero `data_2 = data_2.reset_index()` y luego lo mismo de antes `data_2.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: tuple(x), axis=1)`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Christian lo mas facil seria utilizar pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
#leer excel, tambien puedes especificar el nombre de tu hoja con sheetname = 'nombre_hoja'

df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Copicompu\Desktop\Libro2.xlsx', header = 0)
#usamos solo las columnas de coordenas, eliminamos la columna Estacion, 
#loc nos permite acceder a columnas
df = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Estacion']

#funcion para extraer coordenadas cada n datos, devuelve una lista de tuplas.
def extraer_datos(df, n): 
    contador = 0
    lista_datos = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_records(index=False)] 
    #transformamos el dataframe a lista de tuplas
    nueva_lista = [] #lista donde guardaremos los datos cada n datos
    for i in range(len(lista_datos)):
        contador += 1
        if contador == n:
            contador = 0 #resetear contador
            nueva_lista.append(lista_datos[i])
    return nueva_lista
#despues ejecutamos la funcion 
datos_finales = extraer_datos(df, 3) #extraemos los datos cada 3 datos
datos_finales #variable lista de tuplas cada n datos
```

Comment: existe pandas para hacerlo más simple, no más complejo. Además... viste mi respuesta?

Comment: si, el groupby es buena opcion pero si son millones de datos se puede caer por memoria o demorar horas, es solo otra opcion usando list comprehension

Comment: es verdad pero se necesitan demasiados datos y si fuese el caso se podría optar por usar dask dataframe :)